# Can I combine a foreach and a LINQ query into one?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# code that looks like this:

```
foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                     .Where(e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                                 e.State == EntityState.Added))
{
    IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
    e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

This seems to be like a combination of foreach and LINQ. Can sometone tell me is it possible for me to remove the foreach and combine this into one LINQ statement

Comment: I recommend using LINQ for the part without side effect, and foreach for the side effect part, in this case the mutation of `e`.

Comment: You could. Please do not. Use a *query* to *ask a question*. Use a `foreach` to *perform an action*. Do not use queries to perform actions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd suggest not doing this. Keep everything as readable as possible:

```
var auditableTables = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
                                        .Select(e => e.Entity)
                                        .OfType<IAuditableTable>();

foreach (var table in auditableTables)
{
    table.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

My rule of thumb for coding - if you can't read it like a sentence, then it needs fixing.

Comment: Very true :) While the other answers looks like just for answering the question, this one really suggests a neat way to handle situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The best  you could do is

```
foreach (var entry in from x in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                      where x.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                            x.State == EntityState.Added
                      select (IAuditableTable)x.Entity)
{
    entry.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

There is no query syntax for updates.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable && e.State == EntityState.Added)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(entry => {
        IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable) entry.Entity;
        e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    });
```

Comment: -1 This will create additional overhead and is even less readable that code in original post.

Comment: Can you explain what the additional overhead is? Thanks

Comment: @Borys - is the .ToList() needed? I would have thought the .ForEach would have done the same as the .ToList() ?

Comment: @SamanthaJ Additional amount of work that is not needed. And yes, `ToList()` is required here, since `ForEach` method is defined in `List`.

Comment: Hold on, the question is not about efficiency, but whether it is possible. And answer yes, it is possible, you might not like it, but Microsoft did invented ForEach() and provided capability to use foreach in LINQ style

Comment: @BorysGeneralov 1. `ForEach` behaves way, way differently from `foreach`. `ForEach` uses `for` loop in .NET 4 and `while` in .NET 4.5. In .NET 4.0 this allows you to cause undefined behavior. Fortunately, there's a _version_ check in .NET 4.5 (throws `InvalidOperationException`). Basically, saying that `foreach (var e : enumerable) {}` is the same as enumerable.ToList().ForEach(e => {})` is totally wrong. 2. For metro apps this won't compile, because `ForEach` is gone there.

Comment: 3. Efficiency is always the important especially with collections.

Comment: @DavidBainbridge, that's true (and I gave him a +1 for it), but answering the _problem_ rather than the _question_ (which are not necessarily the same things!) is acceptable on SO, so far as I know.

Comment: @DavidBainbridge While true, SO is also about _good_ code. We don't want some dummy coming along and just copy-pasting this bad code into their application. This answer should say, "Yes, it is possible: <code> However, this has additional overhead because..."

Comment: You might also want to include either `.Cast` or `.OfType` to simplify the foreach lambda.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                e.State == EntityState.Added)
    .ToList().ForEach(entry => {
        IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
        e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    });
```

Comment: -1 While this is working this method is very processor intensive, you actually enumerating the enumerable twice, once with `ToList()` and once with the `ForEach()` call.

Comment: @ISun It's important to note the double enumeration here but it answers the question, I don't think it deserves the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the backup @asawyer, as you said this is the exact answer to OPs question. Does not claim any perfection. And if you look at my comment on accepted answer, you'll see that I accepted that answer is the best one.

Comment: You can right a ForEach extension for IEnumarable that behaves the same way as the list ForEach and just use a normal foreach loop in the extension.